# Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4ms NameError (uninitialized constant Site::Whois)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, whois

I'm using whois gem and i work great in development. When i upload it in production i have such error:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4ms
NameError (uninitialized constant Site::Whois):
app/models/site.rb:11:in `get_whois'
app/controllers/whois_controller.rb:11:in `show'
```

my get_whois method is

```
  def get_whois
    c = Whois::Client.new
    @array = c.query(@site_domain)
  end
```

and error is Whois::Client.new

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `Whois` library is not correctly loaded in your production environment at the time you try to use it in the `Site` model.

Comment: how can i test how it is loaded in model?